# How to assign unique variables from observations in a data frame

Tags: python

I have 1000 observations in a data frame and need each row to be assigned to a variable.

For example
My data set has 1 column with 1000 rows. Each row is a string

```
Column 1
apple
orange
pineapple
```

I would like to use a code that does the following

```
A1 = apple
A2 = orange
A3 = pineapple
```

I have tried turning the DF into a list, using globals function, transposing the data from rows to columns...I don't know which function to use! It looks like pandas may have a solution, but I don't know where to start.

```
for i in df:
    df= globals()
    df["A" + str(i)]
```

I am getting a key error, which I believe is due to `'A'` not being in the data frame. I have added `A` to the data frame, added `A0` through `A1000` in an adjacent column, but I can't get it to work.

As mentioned above, I would like each observation to be assigned to a variable of `A(i)`

I have a for loop later in the code that uses variables `A1` through `A1000`

Thank you in advance for any help or direction on what functions to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
data = ['apple', 'orange', 'pineapple']
i = 1
for c in data:
    exec("%s='%s'" % ('A'+str(i), c))
    i += 1

print(A1)
```

Comment: I think this will work. I tried it on my laptop, but I ran out of memory. I fibbed a bit when I said I had 1000 variables to assign. I actually have 187200 variables to assign. I will try it again on my work computer tomorrow and let you know. Thank you for the quick suggestion.

Comment: 187k variables are a lot of variables. Make sure to mark the question as solved if this worked for you ;)

Comment: So I tried it on my work computer and it assigned the first variable correctly. However, I'm getting a "syntax" error within my string. so my variable looks like this: A1 = '       Apple   how can I remove the quotation mark?

Comment: Try ```"%s=%s"``` instead of ```"%s='%s'"```.

Comment: taking out the additional ' ' changes it to an EOL while scanning string literal error. I think this is the right code, just got to figure out why my data isn't working with it!

Comment: I rebooted my program and did "%s = %s" and it worked!! Just needed some python magic ;) Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'm glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Until and unless you do not want to store that variable inside the DataFrame itself, you can use use Dictionary data structure to create different keys (which will act as your variables dynamically created) and assign them each row of your data frame as value.

```
dict = {}
size_of_dataFrame = 0
while size_of_dataFrame < 10000:
    "Generate random unique key"
    key = ...
    "pull data out of dataframe using iterator"
    value = ...
    dict[key] = value 
   size_of_dataFrame += 1
```

I hope this make sense.

ATB

Comment: sorry this is such a late response. I was trying the other solution to see if I could get it to work. I am unfamiliar with dictionaries in Python (I am very new!) In this code where do I reference the CSV file?

Comment: @CandiceSessa you can read the **csv** in dataframe first ( in pyspark you do it as **dataframe = spark.read.csv("path to csv file")**, need to figure out same if you are using pandas dataframe ) and then manipulate the code. Once you read the CSV in dataframe, perform the count action on the dataframe to get the actual size of the dataframe and then replace the 10000 with that count in while loop.

Comment: So if you are using pandas data frame you read csv as follow  import pandas as pd  dataframe = pd.read_csv("path to csv") .